# ?next= in Django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I often see that "?next=" is used in Django templates, but I could not find any documentation on that online either in HTML or Django. I would appreciate it if anybody could explain what it does or give some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the default parameter django uses to determine redirect URL after login

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

This GET parameter gets passed to the login form as a hidden input called "next" - upon posting the login form, django redirects to the URL provided in the hidden input.